# Will the Steam edition of Witcher 2 have a Polish language version?

Tags: steam, the-witcher-2

I'm buying the game in Canada, but I'd like to play the Polish version.

I heard that after registering the game players will be able to download the add-on for a fully localized Polish version of the game, but does this apply to the Steam version as well? Can you install that add-on on any version of the game?

Comment: As far as I remember, the game was developed in English and translated to Polish (strange as it sounds). Not an answer to your question, but supposedly this way the English version is better than W1's.

Answer (score 1):

"Only those will be on Steam: English, German, French, Italian, Spanish

Polish language pack will be dowlodable"

add-on language packs work fine with steam.The problem is with version of game(v1.1,v1.2 ...)since language packs need to corespond to the game version they get outdated and produce audio bugs.

Comment: You should cite your source here as well.